# Why isn't context variable (state) updated immediately in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state, react-context

I have created a React context as follows (don't mind the any types. I'll deal with that later):

```
// File: AuthContext.ts
const AuthContext = React.createContext<AuthContextDataType | null>(null);

export default AuthContext;
```

I have then wrapped the whole app in the context provider as follows:

```
// File: _app.ts
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  // Sign out the user, memoized
  const logout = React.useCallback(() => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setUser(null);
  }, []);

  // Memoize the full context value
  const authContextValue = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      isAuthenticated,
      setIsAuthenticated,
      user,
      setUser,
      logout,
    }),
    [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated, user, setUser, logout]
  );

  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContextValue}>
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)};
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now when I set the `isAuthenticated` variable in an async function in a component that uses the context variable and try to log it to console as follows:

```
authContext.setIsAuthenticated(true);
console.log(authContext.isAuthenticated);
```

I get the old value and not the newly set one. Why is this and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, like in your example, the `console.log` function runs before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // Do whatever...
}, [authContext.isAuthenticated]
```

The callback will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Now I can do stuff with the variable after changing it.